# SuiteScript 2.0 detect change on custom field with client script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I deployed a client script that handles a click event on a custom button.  When I click the button, I may an api call to get data and the field is populated with the data.  This part works great, but when I go to save the new information on the record, I get this alert:

```
   The record has not changed.  Do you really want to submit it?
```

Is there some way to trigger a form changed event or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setWindowChanged(window,true)